# Machine Learning: How to detect the independent variables that are generating a dependent boolean value

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data-science

I'm Trying to use machine learning in my job, but I can't find a way to adapt it to what I need. And I don't know if it is already a known problem or if I'm working with something that doesn't have a known solution yet.
Let's say that I have a lot of independent variables, encoded as onehot, and a dependent variable with only two status: True (The result had an error) and False (The result was successful)

My independent variables are the parameters I use for a query in an API, and the result is the one that returned the API.

My objective is to detect a pattern where I can see in a dataset in a certain timeframe of a few hours, the failing parameters, so I can avoid to query the API if I'm certain that it could fail.

(I'm working with millions of queries per day, and this mechanism is critical for a good user experience)

I'll try to make an example so you can understand what I need.
Suppose that I have a delivery company, I count with 3 trucks, and 3 different routes I could take.

So, my dummy variables would be T1,T2,T3,R1,R2 and R3 (I could delete T3 and R3 since there are considered by the omission of the other 2)
Then, I have a big dataset of the times that the delivery was delayed. So: Delayed=1 or Delayed=0

With this, I would have a set like this:

```
T1_|_T2_|_T3_|_R1_|_R2_|_R3||Delayed
------------------------------------
_1_|_0__|_0__|_1__|_0__|_0_||____0__
_1_|_0__|_0__|_0__|_1__|_0_||____1__
_0_|_1__|_0__|_1__|_0__|_0_||____0__
_1_|_0__|_0__|_0__|_1__|_0_||____1__
_1_|_0__|_0__|_1__|_0__|_0_||____0__
```

Not only I want to say "in most cases, truck 1 arrives late, it could have a problem, I shouldn't send it more", that is a valid result too, but I also want to detect things like: "in most cases, truck 1 arrives late when it goes in the route 1, probably this type of truck has a problem on this specific route"

This dataset is an example, the real one is huge, with thousand of dependent variables, so it could probably have more than one problem in the same dataset.

example: truck 1 has problems in route 1, and truck 3 has problems in route 1.

example2: truck 1 has problems in route 1, and truck 3 has problems in any route.

So, I would make a blacklist like:

example: Block if (truck=1 AND route=1) OR (truck=3 AND route=1)

example2: Block if (truck=1 AND route=1) OR truck=3

I'm actually doing this without machine learning, with an ugly code that makes a massive cartesian product of the independent columns, and counts the quantity of "delayed". Then I choose the worst delayed/total proportion, I blacklist it, and I iterate again with new values.

This errors are commonly temporary, so I would send a new dataset every few hours, I don't need a lifetime span analysis, except that the algorithm considers these temporary issues.

Anyone has a clue of what can I use, or where can I investigate about it?

Don't hesitate to ask for more info if you need it.

Thanks in advance!

Regards

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.  The root of your question is looking for an introductory tutorial in ML or off-line resources.

Comment: That said, look into ML techniques: principal component analysis, decision trees, and naive Bayes.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply. Yes, sorry, I know is not a common question here, but I'm not really looking for a tutorial. I know the most common methods (multilinear, polynomial, svr, decission tree, etc) but I didn't found any example of their use with the requirements I need. (Like, a+b is 1, c+d is 1, but a+d shouldn't be 1), so I thought that they won't work, and maybe there was some crazy thing that fits perfectly :p
I'll give a try with these methods on my dataset. Thanks!

Comment: in which case, it appears that you're asking for an off-site reference, a specifically proscribed type of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out the scikit-learn package for machine learning classifiers (Random Forest is an industry standard). For this problem, you could feed a portion of the data (training set, say 80% of the data) to the model and it would learn how to predict the outcome variable (delayed/not delayed).

You can then test the accuracy of your model by 'testing' on the remaining 20% of your data (the test set), to see if your model is any good at predicting the correct outcome. This will give you a % accuracy. Higher is better generally, unless you have severely imbalanced classes, in which case your classifier will just always predict the more common class for easy high accuracy.

Finally, if the accuracy is satisfactory, you can find out which predictor variables your model considered most important to achieve that level of prediction, i.e. Variable Importance. I think this is what you're after. So running this every few hours would tell you exactly which features (columns) in your set are best at predicting if a truck is late.

Obviously, this is all easier said than done and often you will have to perform significant cleaning of your data, sometimes normalisation (not in the case of random forests though), sometimes weighting your classifications, sometimes engineering new features... there is a reason this is a dedicated profession.

Essentially what you're asking is "how do I do Data Science?". Hopefully this will get you started, the rest (i.e. learning) is on you.